# what is the size of variable defined in #define macro?

Tags: c

```
int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
printf("%d",sizeof(TOTAL_ELEMENTS));
```

here is my some piece of sample code. the array is an integer type. so, the `array[0]` is also an integer. division of an integer by an integer should yield an integer. But, when I try to find the size of `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` by using `sizeof()` operator, it shows 8 bytes. why??

Comment: `printf("%d",sizeof(TOTAL_ELEMENTS));` --> `printf("%d", (int)TOTAL_ELEMENTS);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, yes, but it's much better to use the correct conversion `%zu` and avoid the cast.

Comment: @TobySpeight BLUEPIXY comment code does has an advantage of working on earlier/not-compliant  versions of C. including what OP _might_ be using.  Still `%zu` is more up-to-date.

Answer (score 7):

Your use of the macro expands to something like `sizeof (sizeof ....)`.  Since the result of `sizeof` is a `size_t`, you're getting `sizeof (size_t)`, which is evidently 8 on your platform.

You probably wanted

```
printf("%zu\n", TOTAL_ELEMENTS);
```

(Note that `%d` is the wrong conversion specifier for a `size_t`, and a good compiler will at least warn about your version.)

---

Here's a complete program that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};
    size_t const TOTAL_ELEMENTS = (sizeof array) / (sizeof array[0]);

    printf("%zu\n", TOTAL_ELEMENTS);
}
```

Output:

```
7
```

---

Note that I made `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` be an ordinary object, as there's no need for it to be a macro here.  You may need it as a macro if you want a version that will substitute the array name, like this:

```
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS(a) (sizeof (a) / sizeof (a)[0])
```

You'd then write:

```
printf("%zu\n", TOTAL_ELEMENTS(array));
```

Comment: I would say "Note that I made TOTAL_ELEMENTS be an ordinary object" or "variable" as `TOTAL_ELEMENTS`  in `size_t TOTAL_ELEMENTS = ...` is not a _constant_ in C.  `const size_t TOTAL_ELEMENTS = ..` is closer, to a wannabe _constant_.  Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: @chux, I thought I *had* written `const` there when I wrote that - now fixed (and I like your suggestion of "object" as a better descriptive term).

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `#define` the pre-processor replaces `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` with `(sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))`.

The result type of `(sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))` is a `size_t`. When you use `sizeof` operator on a `size_t` it will return its size. In your case 8 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` returns a size as type `size_t`, as per [6.5.3.4p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#)

Your platform's `sizeof(size_t)` is `8`.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` returns the size of an item, **in bytes**.  Since a lot of types are larger than a single byte, if you have an array, one way to determine its size **in elements** is to take the total size in bytes of the array, then divide it by the size of the type of element it's composed of - and that type will be in the first element of the array, at index 0.

For example, if I have an array of `int`s, and an `int` is 4 bytes on my platform, it would look like this in memory

```
Item 0 | Item 1 | Item 2
4bytes | 4bytes | 4bytes
```

`sizeof(array)` would be 12, the array's total size in bytes. `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` would be 3, the array's total size in elements.

You're using the macro wrong in your code. You should be using:

```
printf("%zu", TOTAL_ELEMENTS);
```

Otherwise the code expands to `sizeof(sizeof ...)` which is not what you want if you're actually after the length of elements in the array. `sizeof(sizeof(something))` will return the size of a `size_t` type on your platform, which is why you're seeing 8.

Comment: The first few paragraphs just restate what the asker already knows - the actual useful answer is hidden in the "By the way..." edit.